# How can I fix it? libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion

Tags: c++, exception, runtime-error

```
#define REP(i,a,b) for(int i = a; i < b; i++)
#define FOR(i,n) REP(i,0,n)
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
```

Function below is the function which summarizes two big integers by string method. The input can be bigger than the limit of long long int.

```
string string_add(string a, string b) {
    string new_str = "";
    reverse(a.begin(), a.end());
    reverse(b.begin(), b.end());

    string long_s;
    string short_s;
    if (a.size() >= b.size()) {
        long_s = a;
        short_s = b;
    }
    else{
        long_s = b;
        short_s = a;
    }
    int carry = 0;
    int dif = long_s.size() - short_s.size();
    FOR(i, dif)
        short_s += "0";
    FOR(i, long_s.size()) {
        int hab = stoi(long_s.substr(i, 1)) + stoi(short_s.substr(i, 1)) + carry;
        if (hab > 9) {
            carry = 1;
            hab -= 10;
        }
        else carry = 0;

        new_str += to_string(hab);
    }
    if (carry != 0) new_str += to_string(carry);
    reverse(new_str.begin(), new_str.end());
    return new_str;
}
```

And below is the main part.

```
int main() {
    while(!cin.eof()){
        int n;
        string dp[251];
        cin >> n;
        dp[0] = 1;
        dp[1] = 1;
        REP(i,2,n)
            dp[i] = string_add(string_add(dp[i-2], dp[i-2]), dp[i-1]);
        cout << dp[n];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snifV.png)

How can I fix this error? I think the problem is input of 'stoi'.. but I don't know how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you have non-digits in your strings, like space or newline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

> Exceptions: std::invalid_argument if no conversion could be performed

Looks like one of the strings that you're operating on cannot be converted to an integer, and therefore `stoi` is throwing an exception.  In general, it's a good idea to know about all the failure modes of functions you're invoking -- you'll want to handle this case by catching this exception somewhere in your program logic (or by guaranteeing that the strings sent to `stoi` will always be convertible, which may be possible in some use cases).